# I am trying to use values of column in web scraping to get results in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

I am practicing web scraping I am new to this and am trying to scrape amazon using their product ids. so, suppose I have a list of product ids

```
asin = ['B09DKZYBR5','B098QGLXXY','B09BQV32W2']
```

now I want to use each list value at a time to create a list of product name
so I tried

```
for i in asin:
page = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com.au/dp/" + {i})
soup = page.content
doc = BeautifulSoup(soup, "html.parser")
data = []

data.append({
name = doc.find_all(class_="a-size-large product-title-word-break")[0].parent.find('span').string
})
```

then when I do this

```
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want something like this

```
    name
0   Auriko Cat Teaser Toy with Wooden Hand..
1   Cactus Cat Scratching Posts Pole Tree...
2   LNLtoy 8 Cat Toys Kitten Toys Assortme..
```

i am getting this error

```
File "C:\Users\Parth\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_21420/2238400382.py", line 2
    page = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com.au/dp/" + {i})
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do this in append {name:doc.find_all(class_="a-size-large....}

Comment: so no curly braces? u mean

Comment: Use curly braces but instead of  name= ...make it like this name:

Comment: same error how to solve the error. I don't think its getting values of I from list but idk why

Comment: I am getting this error 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

IndexError Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_31648/3806747192.py in <module>  soup = page.content  doc = BeautifulSoup(soup, "html.parser") --->  name = doc.find_all(class_="a-size-large product-title-word-break")[0].parent.find('span').string IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I think your problem in the array ...try print it step by step to get where the error is .

Answer (score 0):

The main cause of your error is because the [identation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) in your for loop is not properly done
To get the solution you want, this should work:

```
asin = ['B09DKZYBR5','B098QGLXXY','B09BQV32W2']
data = []
for i in asin:
    page = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com.au/dp/" + str(i))
    soup = page.content
    doc = BeautifulSoup(soup, "html.parser")
    name = doc.find_all(class_="a-size-large product-title-word-break")[0].parent.find('span').string
    data.append(name)
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":data})
```